# Perl - Master script calling sub-scripts and return status

Tags: perl, system, status

Here's the design I want to accomplish in Perl:

A master script calls multiple sub-scripts. The master script controls the calling of each sub-script in a particular sequence and records output from each sub-script in order to decide whether on not to call the next script.

Currently, I have a master script that calls the sub-script using a system() call, but I am having trouble having the sub-script communicate back status to the master script.

Do not want to use sub functions, would really like to keep each of the sub-script code separate.

To shed more light on the problem:
The sub script should decide what to report back to the master script. For eg: sub script sends code 1 when sub script finds a string value in the database, it sends a code 2 when the sub string doesn't find the file its looking for, and sends a code of 0 when everything goes fine.

Comment: While not an answer to the question, you may want to consider your implementation here.  You could do the same thing, but more robustly, with less memory, and without system calls if you used Modules for the different functionality.  You could have each module have the function or behavior you need.  For those "scripts that need to stay separate", you can have a wrapper script around that module that calls the module's method(s).  Then, for this 'master' script, you simply use all modules and call the functions in each of them, passing results back as variables instead of return values.

Comment: Yes, eventually I would definitely like to go that route, is there a good resource you can point me to learn more about "modules" in perl?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html . Plus, a couple of  OO tutorials here: http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use `exit` codes for this?

```
my $code = system( 'perl', '-e', 'exit 2;' ) >> 8; # $code = 2
say "\$code=$code";
```

Exit codes *can* be 255 *distinct* values.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute and capture output from system commands with backtick syntax.

```
# get result as scalar
$result = `ls -lA`;

# get the result as an array, each line of output is a separate array entry
@result = `ls -lA`;
```

Whenever you use the backtick syntax, the exit status of the command is also stored in the automatic variable `$?`

You can then have the master script decide if the output is good or not using whatever logic you need.

Comment: Using the backtick captures everything that is printed by the sub-script. What I am looking for is basically sending an exit status, except the exit status can be more than 2 distinct values that is set in the sub script

Comment: Use the `$?` variable to capture the exit status as above. You could just discard the output then. This requires the subscripts to send a real status using Perl's `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Axeman's answer you could use the [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system $EXITVAL EXIT_ANY);


system( [2], 'perl', '-e', 'exit 2' );
say "EXITVAL: $EXITVAL";
```